# .NET Core 2.0 - Azure Function, Exception during runtime resolution of assembly

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I'm running a .NET Standard 2.0 Azure function which references another .NET Standard 2.0 class library.

I'm able to build the function which references the class library. But when I run a specific function which uses the class library I get an exception.

```
Exception during runtime resolution of assembly 'StorageQueueStandard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null': 'System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.AppDomain cannot be cast to [B]System.AppDomain. Type A originates from 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.5\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'.
    [21-2-2018 08:48:47]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionAssemblyLoader.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\FunctionAssemblyLoader.cs:line 69'
    [21-2-2018 08:48:47] Unable to find assembly 'StorageQueueStandard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
```

"StorageQueueStandard" is the name of the class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my problem I deleted my project and created a new azure .net standard function with Visual Studio.

After that I downgraded WindowsAzure.Storage to 8.6.0.

For more information visit: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/322

Answer (score 0):

> [A]System.AppDomain cannot be cast to [B]System.AppDomain.

This can happen when the assembly is loaded from different dlls.

As the error shows, both of System.Private.CoreLib and System.Runtime.Extensions have System.AppDomain.

Please check your code and check refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2014). The issue shows that the new **.NET Core doesn't yet support ServiceBus trigger during runtime**.

I am not clear where you have this error, so if you still have this problem, hope you could show me more detailed code and description.

Comment: The azure function only has a http trigger. Turns out the versions of nuget packages were causing the bug.